# How to get an object with change tracking in Dapper .Contrib?

Tags: orm, dapper

I've been playing with Dapper-Contrib for a bit and having problem retrieving an object using .Get so that I can maintain change tracking for the object.

My Interface:

```
Imports Dapper.Contrib.Extensions

Public Interface ICountry

    <Key>
    Property CountryGUID As Guid
    Property Country As String

End Interface
```

The Class:

```
Imports Dapper.Contrib.Extensions

<Table("Country")>
Public Class Country
    Implements ICountry
    <Key>
    Public Property CountryGUID As Guid Implements ICountry.CountryGUID
    Public Property Country As String Implements ICountry.Country

End Class
```

My function:

```
   Public Function Find(countryId As Guid) As ICountry
        Dim country As ICountry

        Using conn = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
            conn.Open()

            country = conn.Get(Of ICountry)(countryId)

            conn.Close()
        End Using

        Return country
    End Function
```

And I got an error saying **Invalid object name 'Countrys'** when calling the above function.

The problem seems to be caused by Dapper sqlmapperextensions automatically adds “s” to tablename and that can be solved by defining TableAttribute. However, TableAttribute is supported for classes only but not interfaces.

Please note that I have to call `.Get` with an interface to have tracking functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and managed to circumvent it.

Looking at the test suite Dapper Contrib, I found [this code](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/99e6b963ab35246abd100a98ef611792ea7e389e/Dapper.Contrib/SqlMapperExtensions.cs#L250). So I created a function to modify the table mapping

```
private static void ConfigureTableMapper()
{
    if (SqlMapperExtensions.TableNameMapper != null)
        return;

    SqlMapperExtensions.TableNameMapper = (type) =>
    {
        var tableattr = type.GetCustomAttributes(false).SingleOrDefault(attr => attr.GetType().Name == "TableAttribute") as dynamic;
        if (tableattr != null)
            return tableattr.Name;

        var name = type.Name;
        if (type.IsInterface && name.StartsWith("I"))
            name = name.Substring(1);
        return name;
    };
}
```

It's C# code but should be easily converted to VB.

Hope this helps !